# How to avoid problems associated with poor questions quality?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, post-ban, low-quality-posts

Because I would like to avoid problems (ban etc.) associated with poor questions on Stack Exchange, I would like to ask if is there a problem for the quality monitoring engine when my questions are not answered but are discussed only.

My first question won't be answered it seems - [How to use global libraries setting in Netbeans on more computers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296455/how-to-use-global-libraries-setting-in-netbeans-on-more-computers)

My second question is only discussed but no answer can be accepted - [How to work with configuration in Spring MVC web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314724/how-to-work-with-configuration-in-spring-mvc-web-application)

Can be this situation be a problem for the site's quality monitoring engine? Is there something I can do to improve the quality of my questions? (I'm not sure, just asking).

Comment: Not sure what's your point. There is no "site quality monitoring engine", the post ban is based only on votes: enough downvotes on enough posts, and the ban is triggered.

Comment: `My second question is only discussed but no answer can be accepted` - Does the discussion give you any clue in solving the problem? If you get the problem solved yourself, you can go ahead and post your solution and mark your own solution as accepted.

Comment: @nhahtdh - actually there is no problem (I expected that my solution is not correct), debaters practically confirmed my solution so there is no need to post another solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not getting answers doesn't put you in danger of a question ban. As long as they don't get downvoted, closed, or deleted, you're fine.

When people answer in comments, encourage them to expand it and post as an answer. If people use comments to request clarification, edit your post so that this happens.